# Horizontally center a <div> which width and height are absolute

Tags: html, css, centering

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div) but still ain't able to center the inner `<div>` :

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="game" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

It must be related to the `position: absolute;` property but it is required in order to insert absolute-position `<img>` elements in the inner `<div>`.

Comment: Why you need `position: absolute`?

Comment: I need it to insert `<img>` elements which position is absolute in the inner `<div>`. Question edited.

Comment: Then you should use `position: relative` on `div.game` and may be `position: absolute` on `img`s.

Comment: `text-align` will only center `inline` elements - `div` elements are *not* inline, they are `block`. To center a div in another div, you'd normally use `margin: 0 auto;` on the child, *however*, this won't work with `position: absolute;`. Can you post an image or something that might help us see what you're after? I have a feeling you're approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: It does not work when only the `<img>` elements have  `position: absolute;` property. The `<div>` elements also must have it.

Edit : yes, maybe I'm on the wrong way. I'm going to post an image.

Comment: The div with class ="game"  set margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto

Comment: [This](https://i.snag.gy/gopIEL.jpg) is what happens when only the `<img>` elements have `position: absolute`. [This](https://i.snag.gy/6x8dD3.jpg) is when the `<div>` element also has it. Edit : @meddy nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, add this:

```
.game {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Since the width is given `left` and `right` will not affect your elements width. `margin: 0 auto;` will do the positioning

### Example:

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="game" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="game" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="game" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Just add

```
  left: 0;
  right:0;
```

To the game class, and it will be horziontally centered. The trick here is to set the position to left 50%, and margin left to minus 1 half of the container width. Let me know if this solves it for you.

EDIT: helpful comments have shown me that we do not need the margin left negative, we can just set the left and right attribute for horizontal alignment. This is better because it will work regardless of the width of the element

Comment: margin-left: -50px; really ?

Comment: Horizontally there are better solutions. As for vertical allignment this is a reliable and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach..

```
.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="game" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/E0xL0KyOkU

Answer (score 0):

you can use the image as the background of the class game

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: 60%;
  height:300px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  left: 0;
  top:28%;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="game" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.game {
  border: 5px solid black;
 width:30%; margin:0 auto; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="game">
  test
  </div>
</div>
```